# Real time update with SqlDependency and SignalR in MVC with foreign key

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr

I want to developer a project where the HTML page real time updates where. So I started to search in internet and I found only this working example: http://venkatbaggu.com/signalr-database-update-notifications-asp-net-mvc-usiing-sql-dependency/

Then I tried to adapt it to my project. Let me first explain it with some code.

This is a part of my database diagram:

[image: Database diagram]

And here some code:

```
[Table("Devices")]
public class Device
{
    [Key]
    public long DeviceId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Modello")]
    public long ModelId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Fornitore")]
    public long SupplierId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Numero di serie")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "E' richiesto un numero di serie")]
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Codice fornitore")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string SupplierCode { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Data di acquisto")]
    public DateTime DatePurchase { get; set; }

    public virtual Model Model { get; set; }
    public virtual Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
}

[Table("DeviceTypes")]
public class DeviceType
{
    [Key]
    public long DeviceTypeId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Tipo dispositivo")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "E' richiesto un tipo dispositivo")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Table("HttpPop3")]
public class HttpPop3
{
    [Key]
    public long ID { get; set; }

    public long DeviceId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Mittente")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string sms_num { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Data")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string sms_date { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Testo")]
    [StringLength(255)]
    [Required]
    public string sms_text { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Code")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string sms_code { get; set; }

    public virtual Device Device { get; set; }
}

[Table("Models")]
public class Model
{
    [Key]
    public long ModelId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Prodotto")]
    public long ProductId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Tipo dispositivo")]
    public long DeviceTypeId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Modello")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "E' richiesto un modello")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual DeviceType DeviceType { get; set; }
}

[Table("Products")]
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public long ProductId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Produttore")]
    public long VendorId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Prodotto")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "E' richiesto un prodotto")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Vendor Vendor { get; set; }
}

[Table("Suppliers")]
public class Supplier
{
    [Key]
    public long SupplierId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Fornitore")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "E' richiesto un fornitore")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Indirizzo")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Numero civico")]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Number { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Telefono")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Fax")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Fax { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Email")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

[Table("Vendors")]
public class Vendor
{
    [Key]
    public long VendorId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Produttore")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "E' richiesto un produttore")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class iCareEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DeviceType> DeviceTypes { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Vendor> Vendors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Model> Models { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Device> Devices { get; set; }

    public DbSet<HttpPop3> HttpPop3s { get; set; }
}

public class HttpPop3Repository
{
    iCareEntities db = new iCareEntities();   

    string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["iCareEntities"].ConnectionString;

    public IEnumerable<HttpPop3> GetAllMessages()
    {
        //This method doesn't work

        List<HttpPop3> messages = new List<HttpPop3>();
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [Mittente], [Data], [Testo], [Code] FROM [iCare].[dbo].[HttpPop3View] ORDER BY [Data] DESC", connection))
            {
                command.Notification = null;

                SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connection.Open();

                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    messages.Add(new HttpPop3 { sms_num = (string)reader["Mittente"], sms_date = (string)reader["Data"], sms_text = (string)reader["Testo"], sms_code = (string)reader["Code"] });
                }
            }

        }

        return messages;
    }

    private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
        {
            MyHub.SendMessages();
        }
    }
}

[HubMethodName("sendMessages")]
public static void SendMessages()
{
    IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
    context.Clients.All.updateMessages();
}
```

`HttpPop3` is a SMS machine that makes a POST when it receives a message.

My goal is to make a real time update of the view when a new message is inserted in the `HttpPop3` table. Here the code-behind where the machine makes POST:

```
public partial class _0090C2E7BD56 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private iCareEntities db = new iCareEntities();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request["sms_num"] != null && Request["sms_date"] != null && Request["sms_text"] != null)
        {
            iCare.Models.HttpPop3 httppop3 = new iCare.Models.HttpPop3
            {
                // 0090C2E7BD56 is the serial number of the machine a 1 is its primary key in Devices table

                DeviceId = 1,
                sms_num = Request["sms_num"],
                sms_date = Request["sms_date"],
                sms_text = Request["sms_text"],
                sms_code = Request["sms_code"]
            };

            db.HttpPop3s.Add(httppop3);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

And this works, when a message arrives I have a new row in my table.

After I generated a `HttpPop3Controller` with views:

```
public class HttpPop3Controller : Controller
{
    private iCareEntities db = new iCareEntities();

    // GET: /HttpPop3/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var httppop3s = db.HttpPop3s.Include(h => h.Device);
        return View(httppop3s.ToList());
    }

    // GET: /HttpPop3/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(long? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        HttpPop3 httppop3 = db.HttpPop3s.Find(id);

        if (httppop3 == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(httppop3);
    }

    // GET: /HttpPop3/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.DeviceId = new SelectList(db.Devices, "DeviceId", "SerialNumber");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: /HttpPop3/Create
    // Per proteggere da attacchi di overposting, abilitare le proprietà a cui eseguire il binding. 
    // Per ulteriori dettagli, vedere http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="ID,DeviceId,sms_num,sms_date,sms_text,sms_code")] HttpPop3 httppop3)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.HttpPop3s.Add(httppop3);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.DeviceId = new SelectList(db.Devices, "DeviceId", "SerialNumber", httppop3.DeviceId);
        return View(httppop3);
    }

    // GET: /HttpPop3/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(long? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        HttpPop3 httppop3 = db.HttpPop3s.Find(id);

        if (httppop3 == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        ViewBag.DeviceId = new SelectList(db.Devices, "DeviceId", "SerialNumber", httppop3.DeviceId);

        return View(httppop3);
    }

    // POST: /HttpPop3/Edit/5
    // Per proteggere da attacchi di overposting, abilitare le proprietà a cui eseguire il binding. 
    // Per ulteriori dettagli, vedere http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="ID,DeviceId,sms_num,sms_date,sms_text,sms_code")] HttpPop3 httppop3)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(httppop3).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.DeviceId = new SelectList(db.Devices, "DeviceId", "SerialNumber", httppop3.DeviceId);

        return View(httppop3);
    }

    // GET: /HttpPop3/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(long? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        HttpPop3 httppop3 = db.HttpPop3s.Find(id);

        if (httppop3 == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(httppop3);
    }

    // POST: /HttpPop3/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(long id)
    {
        HttpPop3 httppop3 = db.HttpPop3s.Find(id);
        db.HttpPop3s.Remove(httppop3);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    public ActionResult GetMessages()
    {
        HttpPop3Repository httpPop3Repository = new HttpPop3Repository();
        return PartialView("_HttpPop3List", httpPop3Repository.GetAllMessages());
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

I don't know why in there is also the column [Devices].[SerialNumber] but for me is OK, it helps me to identify which machine received the message.

Here the Index.cshtml that I modified like in the example:

```
    @model IEnumerable<iCare.Models.HttpPop3>

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="httpPop3Table"></div>
    </div>
</div>

    @section Scripts{
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.1.js"></script>
        <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
        <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
                var notifications = $.connection.myHub;

                //debugger;
                // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
                notifications.client.updateMessages = function () {
                    GetAllMessages()

                };
                // Start the connection.
                $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                    alert("connection started")
                    GetAllMessages();
                }).fail(function (e) {
                    alert(e);
                });
            });


            function GetAllMessages() {
                var tbl = $('#httpPop3Table');
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/HttpPop3/GetMessages',
                    contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'html'
                }).success(function (result) {
                    tbl.empty().append(result);
                }).error(function () {

                });
            }
        </script>

    }
```

OK, now the problem. This is my HttpPop3Repository:

```
public class HttpPop3Repository
{
    iCareEntities db = new iCareEntities();   

    string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["iCareEntities"].ConnectionString;

    public IEnumerable<HttpPop3> GetAllMessages()
    {
        //This method doesn't work

        List<HttpPop3> messages = new List<HttpPop3>();
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [Mittente], [Data], [Testo], [Code] FROM [iCare].[dbo].[HttpPop3View] ORDER BY [Data] DESC", connection))
            {
                command.Notification = null;

                SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connection.Open();

                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    messages.Add(new HttpPop3 { sms_num = (string)reader["Mittente"], sms_date = (string)reader["Data"], sms_text = (string)reader["Testo"], sms_code = (string)reader["Code"] });
                }
            }

        }

        return messages;
    }

    private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
        {
            MyHub.SendMessages();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I set the SerialNumber column if the HttpPop3 class doesn't have this property?

Thank you

Comment: Some part is already missing, I done a join in the HttpPop3View:

SELECT     dbo.HttpPop3.ID, dbo.HttpPop3.DeviceId, dbo.Devices.SerialNumber AS [Numero di serie], dbo.HttpPop3.sms_num AS Mittente, dbo.HttpPop3.sms_date AS Data, 
                      dbo.HttpPop3.sms_text AS Testo, dbo.HttpPop3.sms_code AS Code
FROM         dbo.Devices INNER JOIN
                      dbo.HttpPop3 ON dbo.Devices.DeviceId = dbo.HttpPop3.DeviceId

So the SerialNumber value is available but how can I assign it in the HttpPop3 class if there is not any property?

Thank you

Comment: Another question: Can I change the repository code using EntityFramework? Or SqlDependancy always needs a SqlCommand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, someone in another forum suggested me this workaround. I added an VendorName variable in the Product class with the attribute [NotMapped]:

```
[Table("Products")]
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [DisplayName("ID Prodotto")]
    public long ProductID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("ID Produttore")]
    public long VendorID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Prodotto")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "E' richiesto un prodotto")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Vendor Vendor { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [DisplayName("Produttore")]
    public string VendorName { get; set; }
}
```

And my GetAllProducts method became:

```
        public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {
        List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
            query.Append("SELECT dbo.Products.ProductID, dbo.Vendors.Name AS VendorName, dbo.Products.Name AS ProductName ");
            query.Append("FROM dbo.Products ");
            query.Append("INNER JOIN dbo.Vendors ON dbo.Products.VendorID = dbo.Vendors.VendorID");

            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query.ToString(), connection))
            {
                command.Notification = null;

                SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connection.Open();

                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    products.Add(new Product { ProductID = (long)reader["ProductID"], VendorName = (string)reader["VendorName"], Name = (string)reader["ProductName"] });
                }
            }
        }
        return products;
    }
```

So I've a VendorName where assign the value and I don't get the error 'column not exists'.
To write the Sql query I use the SQL Server Management Studio views designer and it works.

I have already some problem.
Everything works if all the columns are filled. If have some null value I can't get anything from database.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Did u started the SQL Dependency at globax.asax

Please look at step 3, earlier this code snippet was missing i updated the post

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        //Start SqlDependency with application initialization
        SqlDependency.Start(connString);
    }

    protected void Application_End()
    {
        //Stop SQL dependency
        SqlDependency.Stop(connString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did it as in your example.

Comment: I tried to do a simpler test without foreign key and I can see the data on first load but when I update the database table dependency_OnChange event doesn't fire.

Comment: Ehi, I'm still working on this. What about a ViewModel between Vendor and Product Classes? How can I do it? Could it works?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check for other info you can get from SqlDependency. For example:

```
private static void Dependency_OnChanged(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    bool updated  = e.Info == SqlNotificationInfo.Update;
    bool changed  = e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change;
    bool isClient = e.Source == SqlNotificationSource.Data;

    bool acceptable = updated && changed && isClient;

    if (acceptable)
    {
        MyHub.SendMessages();
    }
}
```

Another think I should mention is that putting the

```
SqlDependency.Start(connString);
```

into the Application_Start() in Global.asax is not a very good idea if you are creating deployment package with migrations and code first. When you try to deploy this and would like the migrations to create new database for you on the first run, this will crash horribly as you are setting dependency on database which doesn't exist ... yet. Hope this help...

Comment: Hi, SqlDependency.Start(connString) is already present in Global.asax. I don't know why but if use the query for the Products table as SELECT [ProductID], [VendorID], [Name] FROM [dbo].[Products] it works but if I use SELECT Products.ProductID, Products.VendorID, Products.Name FROM Products the event doesn't fire. Don't know qhy but it doesn't matter. Now I can make it works with a simple table. But how can I display the Vendors.Name column instead Products.VendorID?

Comment: I'm not clear what are you trying to archive. Are you still talking about the query you've mentioned above? There are also some instructions how to create query for notifications. have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms181122.aspx

Comment: Sorry, it's horrible English. :D My goal is to show a page with the columns Products.ProductID, Vendors.Name and Products.Name but I don't know how to write the code becouse if I add a variable VendorName to Product class I have an error that says that the column VendorName not exists and then in the while loop I haven't a variable where assign the value. Yes, I saw that the query for Sql Notification have some rules. At the moment I'm using View designer and works for the moment. Anyway someone suggested me a workaround and now I will post it! :D